Circle geometry - angle at centre theorem
Given a circle $C$ and points $P$, $Q$, $R$ and $S$ on the circumference such that $PQ$ is parallel to $RS$.
Construct the lines $PR$ and $QS$ and call the intersection point $X$.
It follows that angle $PXS$ is twice angle $PQS$.
However, does it follow that $X$ is the centre?
From standard circle theorems, I would think so but I seem to be able to draw this with $X$ not at the centre but I am not sure why.

$X$ might not exist, as $PR$ and $QS$ could be parallel. Also, $PQ$ and $RS$ could be on the same side of the center, and then the intersection would also be on that side of the center (and, in particular, wouldn't be the center).

We know that the angle at center is twice of the angle at circumference. But the converse of this statement does not hold.

@AngaeMT Why does the converse of this statement not hold?

Imagine you have $\angle PQS=x$, then the circumcenter of $\Delta PQS$, denoted by $G$, is the actual `center' you want. Now consider the circumcircle of $\Delta P,G,S$. If $A$ is a point lying on this circle, then $\angle PAS=\angle PGS=2x$ but it is impossible for every $A$ to be the center you want. Actually your $X$ is just one of the $A$, but you cannot ensure $A=G$. (Give some sketch will understand the case.)

It is a fact that if you have two points $P$ and $S$ on a circle and they subtend angle $\theta$ from another point on the circle, they subtend angle $2\theta$ from the center of the circle. But just as there are many points from which $P$ and $S$ subtend angle $\theta$ (namely, every other point on the same arc from $P$ to $S$), likewise there are many points from which $P$ and $S$ subtend angle $2\theta$.

When $X$ is the center of some circle & $Q$ is on the circumference , then the Construction I have shown is the only Solution. The Circle is necessarily around the triangle $QPY$ where $Y$ lies between $S$ & $X$ at the right location , @DavidK , ensuring that angle at $X$ is twice angle at $Q$.

@Prem I wonder why you tagged me. Your comment is all true, of course, but did it have any relationship to anything I wrote? Did you mean to tag someone else?

Oh I should have been more clear. I was indirectly ( & badly ! ) adding to your comment that out of the many Points which subtend arbitrary $\theta$ & out of the many Points which subtend $2\theta$ , while lying on a common line like $SQ$ , we might have only one common Point like $X$ here. That uniqueness , @DavidK , might then give the unique circle.

Let a circle with center $C$ pass through points $P$, $Q$, $R$, and $S$ in that sequence, where $PQ$ is parallel to $RS$.
Let $X$ be the intersection of the lines $\overline{PR}$ and $\overline{QS}$.
This construction is shown in the figure below.

It follows that $\angle PXS = 2 \angle PQS = \angle PCS$.
Note that $Q$ and $R$ are necessarily on the larger arc from $P$ to $S$, and hence $C$, $Q$, and $R$ are all on the same side of the line $\overline{PS}$.
The point $X$ is also on the same side of the line $\overline{PS}$.
Consider the circle $C'$ through the three points $C$, $P$, and $S$.
The arc $\overparen{PCS}$ of this circle is the locus of all points on the same side of $\overline{PS}$ as $C$ from which $P$ and $S$ subtend an angle equal to $\angle PCS$.
Therefore $X$ is on the arc $\overparen{PCS}$.
That is what you can conclude from the fact that $\angle PXS = 2 \angle PQS$.
Follow this link to the source of the figure. On that page you can click on and move any of the points except for $R$ and $X$ in order to see how the points are related as you change the shape of the circle and the intersecting lines.

Visualization will make things more intuitive.
Consider this :

"Does it follow that $X$ is the Center?"
Paradoxically :YES & NO !!
Here we can see that $PQ$ is Parallel to $RS$ & then we can see that $X$ is not at the center. It is way off-center.
Now , when $\angle PQS = x$ & $\angle PXS = 2x$ , it must be that $\angle QPX = x$
Hence $QX = PX$ ( Isosceles triangle )
CASE 1 : When $X$ is the center of the given circle , then $SX = x$ & $XR = x$
More over , we have Congruent triangles , hence $PQ = RS$
Hence , we must have these two lines on either side of the Center $X$.
Else , $X$ is not the center of the given circle.
CASE 2 : BUT BUT BUT , when  it is not the center of the given circle , then we can see that $SX$ will be longer than $x$ , hence $SX$ is not the radius.
Yet , we can get the Point $Z$ within $SX$ , such that $ZX = x$
Now , we can make the Circle with radius $x$. It will go through $P$ , $Q$ , $Z$ , with center $X$.
That new Circle is shown with shaded sector.
Hence , $X$ is indeed the Center of some other Circle where the Circle theorem continues to hold.

Isn't every point in the plane the center of lots of circles where the Circle Theorem holds?

When OP saw that the inner angle is twice of the outer angle , OP applied Circle theorem in "reverse" to think that $X$ must be the center of the given Circle. I have shown that it is not so. Yet OP is right that such a configuration must have some easy-to-see circle where $X$ is the center , @GerryMyerson , which I have shown too. Alternative way to look at it : In Case the inner angle had been thrice of the outer angle , then there is no such natural easy-to-see circle !

When $X$ is the center of some circle & $Q$ is on the circumference , then the Construction I have shown is the Unique Solution where that Circle is necessarily around the triangle $QPY$ where $Y$ lies between $S$ & $X$ at just the right location , @GerryMyerson , ensuring that the angle at $X$ is twice the angle at $Q$ according to the Circle theorem.
